# Symfony 4 - Accessing joined tables with where clause?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have the following entity:

```
class Orders
{
  ...
      /**
      * One Order has Many Employees.
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Employee")
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="orders_employees",
      *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="employee_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      *      )
      */
      private $employees;
```

I'm trying to do the following:

```
   $orders = $this->getDoctrine()->
        ->getRepository(Orders::class)
        ->findBy(['employees' => $userId);
```

however this doesn't work as it's generating the SQL:

```
... FROM orders t0 WHERE orders_employees.employee_id = ?
```

Basically it's missing the join clause when it generates the SQL. Am I missing something?  I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reverse your logic to get orders for a particular employee like

```
$employee = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Employee::class)->find($userId);
$orders = $employee->getOrders();
```

Or you could use query builder

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Orders::class);
$orders= $repo->createQueryBuilder('o')
                ->select('o')
                ->join('o.employees' ,'e')
                ->where('e.id = :id')
                ->setParameter('id',$userId)
                ->getResult();
```

Comment: If I reverse it, is there a way to do like getOrders()->findBy['date' => $date] if that is a join table too?  Perhaps I should just be using the querybuilder afterall...

Comment: @ElementZero yes you need to use query builder if you want to perform filters on related entities